# I can't setText for fullname and money in AccountController .Error code is "non static variable cannot be referenced from a static context"

Tags: javafx

I can't set Text with static. Please help me set Text for fullname and money in AccountController. Please have me and give me a few examples

I pass String full1 and String money from Menu to Account and set Text have error

Menu Controller class

```
public class MenuController implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    private Text nameuser;

    String account;
    void setData(String fullname, String username) {
        nameuser.setText(fullname);
        account = username;
    }

    @FXML
    private void btnsp(ActionEvent event) throws Exception {
        try {
            Connection con;
            con = Connect.Connect();

            PreparedStatement pstm = con.prepareStatement("select fullname, money from account where username = ?");
            pstm.setString(1, account);
            ResultSet result  = pstm.executeQuery();
            if(result.next()) {
                System.out.println(result.getString(1));
                System.out.println(result.getString(2));
            } else {
                System.out.println("Fail!");
            }
            String fullname1 = result.getString(1);
            String money = result.getString(2);
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Account.fxml"));
            Parent root = loader.load();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            Stage app_stage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
            AccountController MenuController = loader.<AccountController>getController();
            AccountController.setData(fullname1, money);
            app_stage.hide();
            app_stage.setScene(scene);
            app_stage.show();  
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("SQLException");
            System.out.println("Error message: " + ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Account Controller class

```
public class AccountController implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    private Text fullname;
    @FXML
    private Text money;

    static void setData(String fullname1, String money) {
        fullname.setText(fullname1);
        fullname.setText(money);
    }
}
```

Comment: `void setData(...)` should not be static.  Which also means you can't use `AccountController.setData(...)`.  You'll need to instantiate AccountController either manually or through fxml in order to set the data.